# Easiest way to get every word except the last word from a string

Tags: java, string

What is the easiest way to get every word in a string other than the last word in a string?

Up until now I have been using the following code to get the last word:

```
String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
String[] b = listOfWords.split("\\s+");
String lastWord = b[b.length - 1];
```

And then getting the rest of the the string by using the remove method to remove the last word from the string.

I don't want to have to use the `remove` method. Is there a way similar to the above set of code to get the string of words without the last word and last space?

Comment: Do you want each word to be a separate string, or is one string containing everything but the last word ok, too?

Comment: I want every word other than the last word to be in 1 string, and then the last word to be in another string.

Comment: use grouping and define a word as a group but also add a whitespace character after it. Something like `(\w)\s`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this:

```
    String test = "This is a test";
    String firstWords = test.substring(0, test.lastIndexOf(" "));
    String lastWord = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

You could get the lastIndexOf the white space and use a substring like below:

```
String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
int index = listOfWords.lastIndexOf(" ");
System.out.println(listOfWords.substring(0, index));
System.out.println(listOfWords.substring(index+1));
```

Output:

```
        This is a
        sentence
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the method `String.lastIndexOf` in combination with `String.substring`.

```
String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
String allButLast = listOfWords.substring(0, listOfWords.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 3):

I added one line to your code. Nothing was removed here.

```
String listOfWords = "This is a sentence";
String[] b = listOfWords.split("\\s+");
String lastWord = b[b.length - 1];
String rest = listOfWords.substring(0, listOfWords.indexOf(lastWord)).trim(); // Added
System.out.println(rest);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will suit your needs:

```java
.split("\\s+[^\\s]+$|\\s+")
```

For example:

```java
"This is a sentence".split("\\s+[^\\s]+$|\\s+");
```

Returns:

```
[This, is, a]
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting: **[Ljava.lang.String;@ca0b6** when I run the regex. Any ideas?

Comment: @Digitalwolf Because `split` returns an array, and `Ljava.lang.String;@ca0b6` is the representation of an array of strings (i.e. when calling `myArray.toString()`). Just use `Arrays.asList(myArray)` (e.g. `Arrays.asList("This is a sentence".split("\\s+[^\\s]+$|\\s+"))`) to get the result I provided, since a list has a *better* representation (more *user-friendly* let's say `;)`).

Answer (score 2):

```
public class StringArray {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence = "this is a sentence";

        int index = sentence.lastIndexOf(" ");

        System.out.println(sentence.substring(0, index));

    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14339501/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).